# Get a list greater than specific value from lists usinq linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contains multiple lists and I want to select the only ones that have the second value greater than 1

```
List<List<object>> lists = new List<List<object>>();
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "zxc", 0.1, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "dfg", 0.3, 7 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "abc", 0.8, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "fhc", 1.7, 8 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "ghr", 5.5, 9 });
foreach (var list in lists.(LINQ here ?))
    { //TODO
    }
```

I need to perform a foreach loop only with lists that have the second value greater than 1, in this case only lists 4,5 .

Comment: Instead of storing a string, int, and double in a list of objects create a custom class that will hold that data with the correct types.

Comment: Also, in this particular case, and especially if you don't need the list anywhere else, there really isn't anything wrong with doing `var list in lists` and then in the loop testing if `list[1] > 1` and skipping the ones that aren't. LINQ doesn't magically get you out of having to loop through the list either way.

Comment: I've updated the code now, thank you for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As juharr said, use proper classes with properties. But the short and dirty answer would be `lists.Where(l => (double)l[1] > 1);`, but it assumes that you always have at least two objects in your inner lists and that the second one is always a `double`. Which is why you should use a strongly-typed object with strongly-typed properties instead.

The correct way to handle it would be something like:

```
public class MyStuff
{
    public List<MyThing> Things { get; set; }
}

public class MyThing
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public double SomeValue {get; set;}
    public int SomeInt {get; set;}
}

var stuff = new MyStuff()
{
    Things = new List<MyThing>()
    {
        new MyThing() { Name = "dfg", SomeValue = 0.3, SomeInt = 7 },
        new MyThing() { Name = "fhc", SomeValue = 1.7, SomeInt = 8}
    }
};

var filtered = stuff.Things.Where(t => t.SomeValue > 1);
```

But preferably with meaningful class and property names!

In this case, `Things` can only include instances of `MyThing` and nothing else. And `MyThing` will always have a `SomeValue` (which will default to zero, unless you do something else with it) so the `>1` test will never throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code slightly.. it would look like this, I would agree with the other comments, it's best to use strongly typed objects where possible to get compile time checks.

```
List<List<object>> lists = new List<List<object>>();
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "zxc", 0.1, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "dfg", 0.3, 7 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "abc", 0.8, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "fhc", 1.7, 8 });
    lists.Add(new List<object> { "ghr", 5.5, 9 });
var result = lists.Where(o => (double)o[1] > 1).ToList();
```

I'd prefer to do this:

```
private class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string field1, double field2, int field3)
    {
        this.Field1 = field1;
        this.Field2 = field2;
        this.Field3 = field3;
    }

    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public double Field2 { get; set; }
    public int Field3 { get; set; }
}

var lists = new List<MyClass>{
    new MyClass( "zxc", 0.1, 3), 
    new MyClass( "dfg", 0.3, 7), 
    new MyClass( "abc", 0.8, 3), 
    new MyClass( "fhc", 1.7, 8), 
    new MyClass( "ghr", 5.5, 9)  
};
var result = lists.Where(mc => mc.Field2 > 1).ToList();
```